# Instance member 'mediaItem' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio-service

Can't undersand what i'm doing wrong. audio_service library.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AudioHandler.mediaItem.value((MediaItem? item) {
      setState(() {
        _currentMediaItem = item;
      });
    });
  }
```

issue: Instance member 'mediaItem' can't be accessed using static access.

I can't find anything about this in official documentation. In documentation of audio_service said what i need to identify variables as static. I was trying but can't fix that.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to get value of current media item waht playing on phone now

Answer (score 0):

Because `mediaItem` is a getter, and it's not a static getter. This is why you get the error.